# SigninScreen.js and functions.js - how to make function.js function update useState in SigninScreen.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two files: one for functions (functions.js) and one for SigninScreen, please see the code below. How can I make the signInUser formula refer back to the SigninScreen (and e.g. update useState value of email/password there)?

Right now, it seems as if the signInUser function does not have access to that scope because I get error message stating 'setEmail is not a function'.

functions.js

```
export async function signInUser(email, password) {
  console.log('Attempting to sign in');

  credentials = {
  email: email.toString(),
  password: password.toString()
  }

  const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
  };
  const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/signin', requestOptions)
  const data = await response.json()

  setEmail('xaxaxaxa')

  console.log(data)


}
```

SigninScreen.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native'
import { Text, Input } from 'react-native-elements'
import Spacer from '../components/Spacer'
import { signInUser } from '../functions/functions.js'
import UserContext from '../context/appContext.js'


const SigninScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  // This can be removed later
  const user = useContext(UserContext);
  console.log(user);

  return (
  <UserContext.Consumer>
  {({userloggerinfo, updateUserLoggerInfo}) => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Spacer>
      <Text h3>Sign in</Text>
    </Spacer>
    <Input
    label="Email"
    value={email}
    onChangeText={setEmail}
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCorrect={false}
    />
    <Spacer />
    <Input
    secureTextEntry
    label="Password"
    value={password}
    onChangeText={setPassword}
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCorrect={false}
    />
    <Spacer>
      <Button
      title="Sign in"
      onPress={() => { signInUser(email, password); console.log('hejjjjjj'); }}
      />
    </Spacer>
  </View>
  )}
  </UserContext.Consumer>
  )
}

SigninScreen.navigationOptions = () => {
  return {
    header: null
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginBottom: 250
  }
})

export default SigninScreen
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

function.js ---- >

```
export async function signInUser(email, password,setEmail) {
    console.log('Attempting to sign in');

    let credentials = {
    email: email.toString(),
    password: password.toString()
    }

    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
    };
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/signin', requestOptions)
    const data = await response.json()

    setEmail('xaxaxaxa')

    console.log(data)
  }
```

SignInScreen.js ----- >

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import { View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native'
import { Text, Input } from 'react-native-elements'
import Spacer from '../components/Spacer'
import { signInUser } from '../functions/functions.js'
import UserContext from '../context/appContext.js'


const SigninScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  // This can be removed later
  const user = useContext(UserContext);
  console.log(user);

  return (
  <UserContext.Consumer>
  {({userloggerinfo, updateUserLoggerInfo}) => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Spacer>
      <Text h3>Sign in</Text>
    </Spacer>
    <Input
    label="Email"
    value={email}
    onChangeText={setEmail}
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCorrect={false}
    />
    <Spacer />
    <Input
    secureTextEntry
    label="Password"
    value={password}
    onChangeText={setPassword}
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCorrect={false}
    />
    <Spacer>
      <Button
      title="Sign in"
      onPress={() => { signInUser(email, password,setEmail); console.log('hejjjjjj'); }}
      />
    </Spacer>
  </View>
  )}
  </UserContext.Consumer>
  )
}

SigninScreen.navigationOptions = () => {
  return {
    header: null
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginBottom: 250
  }
})

export default SigninScreen
```

Try above code it should work now!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing the return statement did the trick